# why i cant upload with this php code?

Tags: php, web

I want to make a simple picture uploader.

I have two pages 'index.html' and 'upload.php'

Here is the code for index.html

```
<html>
<head>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#im").click(function() {
    $("input[id='my_file']").click();
});
$("#su").click(function() {
    $("input[id='submit']").click();
});    
});
    </script>       
</head>


    <body>

    <form method="post" action="upload.php" >
        <img  id="im" src="pic.png" width="30" height="30" />
        <img   id="su"    src="sent.png" width="50" height="50" />
        <input type="file" id="my_file" style="display: none;" name="img" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit"  style="display: none;" value="Upload Image" name="submit"/> 
    </form>
```

Here is the code for upload.php:

```
<?php

$target_path = "uploads/"; 
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['img']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['img']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "fail : ". $_FILES['img']['error'] ;
}  

?>
```

Also I created the dir uploads and I checked if it is writable and it is .
I edited the php.ini and turned on the upload and raised the max size to 50m

When I upload a file it dispay : "fail : "

Comment: `"when i upload a file it dispay : "fail : "  why ?"` - Because your last line of code explicitly displays that text...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php is your friend, use it on `$_FILES` for example, so see what's really missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have form for uploading files, you need to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` attribute to form.

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one: PHP Code

```html
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Problem is in HTML, not (primarily) in PHP.